# CPU high usage with electron on windows

Tags: sqlite, electron

Electron : 1.4.4

Operating system:windows 7 ,My windows 7 is a virtual machine. 2GB ,1 kernel

node-sqlite3:3.1.8 ,used a db file.

electron-builder:7.24.1

node:7.0.0

I'm working on Mac OS.Make an electron project,using sqlite3 to store data.Every thing is ok on my mac.So I build an installer exe file for windows .Before, I used electron-rebuild.cmd on windows build the sqlite3 module, and success.Then use electron-builder build exe file,and success.When installed to windows,and run the app,the cpu runs 100%.I caught a cpu profile and found only some ajax post take 100ms, nothing else.Then I take a look at the log found that sometimes the database takes a lot time (10m about),sometime it's not. I'm very confusion.I think may be the sqlite3 module has problems.Did any one has ideas about it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well ,if I did not read database just use jsonp send a local request ,the cpu also take 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is a [familiar issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7685), I suggest trying the workaround mentioned in a [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13882#issuecomment-260445798), which is to increase the number of CPU cores available to the VM to at least two.